# Set hidden value based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

### Cannot find an answer:

> *I have searched Stack Overflow, however, despite finding lots of similar posts — and more complicated situations — I still couldn't find an answer to the issue I am trying to solve.*

##### Here's my issue:

I have **four radio buttons**, and one **hidden field:**

---

```
    <!-- My HTML Document -->

    <form action="/my-doc.html" method="post">    

        <!-- The 4 Radio Buttons-->
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="1" checked> First
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="2"> Second
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="3"> Third
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="4"> Fourth

        <!-- The Hidden Field -->      
        <input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="1">
      
        <!-- My Submit Button -->
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Go">
    </form>
```

What I need to do is set the value of `<input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="1">` so that it is 0

###### Like this: `<input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="0">`

...but only after the user selects either the first, or second, radio button. The value of the hidden field should remain as being equal to 1 if any other radio button is selected.

How does a person do this using JavaScript?

---

###### Requirements: *"Looking for a VanillaJS answer."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below option
In javascript

```js
function setValue() {

    var selectedRadio = '';
    var games = document.getElementsByName('game')

    for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
        if (games[i].checked) {
            selectedRadio = games[i].value;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("hdnSelectedRadValue").value = (selectedRadio == "1" || selectedRadio == "2") ? "0" : "1";
    return false;
}
```

Changes to do in HTML side

```html
<body style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
    <form action="some.htm" method="post">    
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="1" checked> First
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="2"> Second
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="3"> Third
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="4"> Fourth
        <input type="text" name="criteria" id="hdnSelectedRadValue">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Go" onclick="setValue();">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radios =
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="game"]');

radios.forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener(
    'change', () => {
        document.getElementsByName("criteria")[0].value =
            parseInt(radio.value, 10) > 2 ? '1' : '0';
    }
));
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="game" value="1" checked> First
<input type="radio" name="game" value="2"> Second
<input type="radio" name="game" value="3"> Third
<input type="radio" name="game" value="4"> Fourth
<input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Go">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply listen to "change" events on all of the radio buttons, then just set the value accordingly.

Here's the snippet code I have written and tested

```js
(function(){
    let hdfValue = document.getElementById("myhiddenfield")
    let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="game"]');
    let submitButton = document.querySelector('input[name="action"]')
  
  radioButtons.forEach((input) => {
        input.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                let radioButtonValue = e.target.value
            if(radioButtonValue == 1 || radioButtonValue == 2){
                hdfValue.value = 0;
            } else {
                hdfValue.value = 1;
            }
        });
    });
  
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(hdfValue.value)
  });
})()
```

```html
<form>    
<input type="radio" name="game" value="1" checked> First
<input type="radio" name="game" value="2"> Second
<input type="radio" name="game" value="3"> Third
<input type="radio" name="game" value="4"> Fourth
<input type="hidden" name="criteria" id="myhiddenfield" value="1">
<input type="button" name="action" value="Go">
</form>
```